# Showing that these sets are closed or not closed under countable unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given an uncountable set $\Omega$, and the two sets:
$$ \mathcal G = \{A \subset \Omega: A \text{ is finite or } A^c \text{ is finite.}\}$$
$$ \mathcal F = \{A \subset \Omega: A \text{ is numerable or } A^c \text{ is numerable.}\}$$

Why is $\mathcal F$ closed under countable unions, but $\mathcal G$ is not?

For $\mathcal G$, I took the sequence $Z_n \in \mathcal G$, and the subsequences $X_n, Y_n \subset Z_n$, where each $X_n$ is finite and each $Y_n^c$ is finite. Then, the c.u $\cup_{n\geq 1} Z_n = (\cup_{n\geq1}X_n) \cup (\cup_{n\geq1}Y_n)$ is not finite because $\cup_{n\geq1}Y_n$ is not finite. However, $(\cup_{n\geq 1} Z_n)^c = (\cap_{n\geq1}X^c_n) \cap (\cap_{n\geq1}Y^c_n)$ should be finite since it is a subset of, for example, $Y^c_1$  which is finite. Therefore, $\mathcal G$ should be closed under countable unions. What am I doing wrong here?

For $\mathcal F$, I did the same replacing finite by countable and concluded that it is closed under countable unions, but I'm not sure if the above procedure is correct.

Comment: How are the $Z_n$ defined?

Comment: @memerson $Z_1, Z_2, ... \in \mathcal G$

Comment: G contains all singletons in $\Omega$. The countable union of all singletons is numerable, but not finite. So G is not closed under countable unions. Similarly countable union of finite sets (other than singletons) need not be finite

Comment: So $Z_n$ is an arbitrary sequence and not a specific one. Thanks for the clarificaiton!

Comment: @RahulMadhavan: I think that is what I did in the first part of my proof. I still have to prove that the complement of the c.u of the singletons is not in G.

Comment: what if $Z_n$ does not contain any $Y_n$ such that $Y_n^C$ is finite?

Comment: @RahulMadhavan: I think I got it. Both the c.u. of $Z_1, Z_2, ...$ and its complement are countable but not necessarily finite. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of distinct points of $\Omega$. Consider the sets $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$, $n=1,2...$. These are all in $\mathcal G$ but their union is not.

Supopose $A_1,A_2,...$ are all in $\mathcal F$.  If each  $A_n$ is countable so is their union. If $A^{c}$ is countable then the complement of $\bigcup A_n$ is countable. In either case $\bigcup A_n \in \mathcal G$.